# Migrating SHA1 passwords generated in PHP to Bcrypt in JavaScript

Tags: php, node.js, bcrypt, sha

I'm coming at the encryption side of things more or less cold, and having spent a few days on this, I need help.

The plan is to mail the users, have them sign in, validate their password against SHA1, and then encrypt the supplied password in Bcrypt, replacing the existing password.

I have a "users" table that contains passwords generated by a combination of [IonAuth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) and [FlexiAuth](https://github.com/haseydesign/flexi-auth) in PHP, and a corresponding salt value for each password.

According to the configuration file for IonAuth, the passwords *should* be SHA1.

I've run a SHA1-encrypted password known to me through an existing Bcrypt method, and it too comes up with false for both password and password with salt, so I've at least eliminated Bcrypt as a possible algorithm.

So, for testing purposes, I'm using a *known and valid* username and password.

I've re-written the application in Vue, Node, Express and so on, and tried:

```
let password = passwordHash.verify(providedPassword + user.salt, user.password)
console.log("Users:password", password)
```

… but that comes up false for both password and password with salt.

I'm using the antique [passwordHash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash) module for Node, since I've not been able to find anything else, and I suspect this won't work given it prepends its hash strings with "sha1"

For reference, the hashed password strings in the "users" table begin with: "$2a$08$…", and those generated by Bcrypt in Node begin with: "$2a$10$…"

Any ideas?

Comment: passwordHash generates its own salt internally -- you do not need to provide your own, the API is doing it for you.  The user.password should be the password from the database.  Please [don't log user passwords](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/github-accidentally-recorded-some-plaintext-passwords-in-its-internal-logs/) in production code.

Comment: Hi @TheGreatContini, as explained, I'm not attempting to recover the password, I'm checking the passwords entered by each user, and — if valid — moving them to Bcrypt.

Comment: If you're not using bcrypt to check the passwords there's no point in using it. Bcrypt should be checking the passwords, I'm not sure why you're using `passwordHash`, it was deprecated six years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're asking:

> According to the configuration file for IonAuth, the passwords should be SHA1.

Ok. It can be whatever they decide; pig-latin if they want.

> I've run a SHA1-encrypted password known to me through an existing Bcrypt method, and it too comes up with false for both password and password with salt, so I've at least eliminated Bcrypt as a possible algorithm.

SHA-1 is not encryption; it's hashing. Did you run the SHA-1 *hashed* password through bcrypt? Or did you run the *password* through bcrypt?

> and it too comes up with false for both password and password with salt

What do you mean salt? bcrypt supplies the salt. You don't supply the salt. 
Ok, so you've eliminated bcrypt.

But what's the issue? Are you unable to login? Your underlying framework is unable to validate its own credentials? Are you getting an authentication error?

Short version: i have **no** idea what you're doing.

But

- regardless of what this Ion Framework says
- regardless of SHA-1
- regardless of salt or not(?!) salt
- regardless of passing the password vs. the sha-1 hash of a password to bcrypt:

It seems like you're asking to identify the hashed passwords being generated somewhere by someone.

Both:

- `$2a$08$…`
- `$2a$10$…`

are absolutely definitely bcrypt.

The first one is bcrypt with a cost factor of `8` (i.e. 2<sup>8</sup> rounds).
The second one is bcrypt with a cost factgor of `10` (i.e. 2<sup>10</sup> rounds).

Whatever it is, it should be using a cost factor of 12 please (so as to take ~250ms to generate).

So i would start by eliminating all the cruft *"helpfully"* supplied by this framework - and call bcrypt.

I'm not dealing with javascript ever again, nor do i know what bcrypt library this is. But every bcrypt library worth its salt has a function like:

```
String hash = bcrypt.hashPassword("hunter2", 12);
```

and

```
Boolean passwordMatch = bcrypt.verifyPassword("hunter2", hash);
```

The fact that someone is trying to append salt to a password:

```
providedPassword + user.salt
```

is absolutely wrong.

## Regardless

If nothing else: those saved strings you showed **are** bcrypt.

- `$1$`: MD5-based crypt ('md5crypt')
- `$2$`: Blowfish-based crypt ('bcrypt')
- `$2a$`: bcrypt; updated to document UTF8 and null terminator
- `$2b$`: bcrypt; generated by OpenBSD without a bug in their earlier version
- `$2x$`: bcrypt hashes generated by one buggy php implementation
- `$2y$`: bcrypt hashes generated by one fixed php implementation
- `$sha1$`: SHA-1-based crypt ('sha1crypt')
- `$5$`: SHA-256-based crypt ('sha256crypt')
- `$6$`: SHA-512-based crypt ('sha512crypt')

You say you've eliminated bcrypt.

I'm guaranteeing you bcrypt.

I suggest you get of this fancy framework, and use bcrypt directly. Once you've verified that you can correctly:

- hash
- store
- verify

passwords using bcrypt, then you can try debugging this undocumented Ion Library.

Comment: Hi, I've explained in the opening message what I'm doing and the purpose behind it. I've tried a password using Bcrypt with and without salt and it's coming up as false.

Comment: As I said at the beginning: "I'm coming at the encryption side of things more or less cold." I've been explicit about the purpose, and adding anything else would involve me saying the same things. I appreciate the effort.